# Regular expression

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex, aspx-user-control

I have an aspx:memo control in asp.net page. The control has a regular expression validator. If the  text inserted in the memo is different than the regular expression then the validator triggers an error.
So I would like to accept every character except these:

```
1) -- (double hyphen)
2) // (double slash)
3) ' (Single quote)
4) \\ (double backslash)
5) ^ (Caret)
6) ; (Semicolon)
```

So far I have created this expression:

```
^[\na-zA-Z0-9 .,~?`~!@():#&%=+΄<>\\\-\/_&quot;\]\[\}\{]*$
```

I have put inside every character that I accept in the memo. So the issue is that with this expression I accept slashes and backslashes or hyphens even if they are single or more.
How can I disallow the double slashes or hyphens but allow single ones.

I have already lost a lot of time for this. Your help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`^((?!--|\/\/|'|\\\\|\^|;).|\w)*$`

## Breakdown

`(?!   )` being the negative look ahead meaning that anything within (separated by `|`) will cause the validation to fail

> `\/\/` being `//` with escaped characters
>
> `\\\\` being `\\` with escaped characters

`.` allows any character (except whitespace)

`\w` allows whitespace

Comment: One issue though. It does not accept \n (pressing enter to change line).

Comment: I guess in order to accept enter I have to put |\n after the \w.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
(?<!\-)(?<!\\)(?<!\/)[^;\^'](?!\-)(?!\\)(?!\/)
```

**Explanation**

`(?<!\-)(?<!\\)(?<!\/)` => Do not match `\` or `/` or `'` before the blacklist.

`[^;\^']` => Our blacklist. Do not match `;` or `'` or `^`, match everything else.

`(?!\-)(?!\\)(?!\/)` => Dot not match `\` or `/` or `'` after the blacklist.

So we allow everything but `;` and `'`. But only, if there is no `\` or `/` or `'` in front or after the character. This means single occurances of these characters are allowed.

**EDIT:**

This matches only single characters. Better use the accepted answer.